# bash rsync is Killed by signal 2

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm trying to prevent the user from cancelling the script by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. The following script executes completely, except `rsync` that insists on dying, displaying the error `Killed by signal 2`.

Is it possible to avoid `rsync` from dying? If so, can I put it in the background, or should it be in the foreground?

script:

```
trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT

cd /tmp
nohup rsync  -e 'ssh -o LogLevel=ERROR' -av --timeout=10 --delete-excluded myapp.war myserver:/tmp/  < /dev/null > /tmp/teste 2> /tmp/teste2

let index=0
while [ $index -lt 400000 ]
do
  let index=index+1
done

echo "script finished"
echo "index:$index"
```

I'm suspecting that the ssh channel is dying before `rsync`. Following the end of the output of the `strace` command in pid of `rsync`:

```
[...]
write(4, "\374\17\0\7", 4)              = 4
select(5, NULL, [4], [4], {10, 0})      = 1 (out [4], left {9, 999998})
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) @ 0 (0) ---
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 255}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 12738
wait4(-1, 0x7fffaea6a85c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
rt_sigreturn(0xffffffffffffffff)        = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 400000}) = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3fcb6326b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3fcb6326b0}, NULL, 8) = 0
wait4(12738, 0x7fffaea6aa7c, WNOHANG, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes)
getpid()                                = 12737
kill(12738, SIGUSR1)                    = -1 ESRCH (No such process)
write(2, "rsync error: unexplained error ("..., 72) = 72
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
exit_group(255)                         = ?
Process 12737 detached
```

Comment: Would it be possible to run the script inside `screen`?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty clear from experimentation that `rsync` behaves like other tools such as `ping` and do not inherit signals from the calling Bash parent.

So you have to get a little creative with this and do something like the following:

```
$ cat rsync.bash
#!/bin/sh

 set -m
 trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
 rsync -avz LargeTestFile.500M root@host.mydom.com:/tmp/. &
 wait

 echo FIN
```

Now when I run it:

```
$ ./rsync.bash
X11 forwarding request failed
building file list ... done
LargeTestFile.500M
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
sent 509984 bytes  received 42 bytes  92732.00 bytes/sec
total size is 524288000  speedup is 1027.96
FIN
```

And we can see the file did fully transfer:

```
$ ll -h | grep Large
-rw-------. 1  501 games 500M Jul  9 21:44 LargeTestFile.500M
```

#### How it works

The trick here is we're telling Bash via `set -m` to disable job controls on any background jobs within it. We're then backgrounding the `rsync` and then running a `wait` command which will wait on the last run command, `rsync`, until it's complete.

We then guard the entire script with the `trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT`.

#### References

- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/360713
- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1539283
- [Delay termination of script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450127/delay-termination-of-script)

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for the duration of the script execution.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
        echo "Oops CTRL-C not allowed!"
}

for i in `seq 1 5`;
do
    echo "doing something... blah blah blah... try pressing Ctrl+C"
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Its always a good idea to put a echo "All Done!" at the end of the script.

Comment: Before you answer , I had added output of the strace command. You could check ? Thanks. (I'm new on the site , the output was unformatted .)

Comment: have you try to put a "sleep 5" at the end of the command and then an echo "All done!"

Comment: Unfortunately it has not worked:

[ jboss sapluiapl01 @ ~] $ cat / tmp / teste2
Killed by signal 2 .
rsync : writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [ sender ] : Broken pipe ( 32)
rsync : connection unexpectedly closed ( 125,595 bytes received so far ) [ sender ]
rsync error: unexplained error ( code 255) at io.c (600 ) [ sender = 3.0.6 ]

Comment: Looks like you have a network/firewall issue. Nothing to do with the script at this point. What does the rsync logs say?

Comment: may be you are hitting the bandwidth limits and hence getting dropped. Have you tryied with --bwlimit

Comment: rsync works perfectly between the two servers. The problem is that would prevent ctrl + c to cancel rsync. I suspect the ssh dies before rsync , but I am still investigating . Thanks.